# Error when filling a TextInput for a Graph with a 0 or a null

Tags: reactjs, graph, charts, native

Every time I enter "0" for the "Eigenverbrauch in kWh" input field from the code below, I get the following error message: `TypeError: data[0].toFixed is not a function. (In 'data[0].toFixed(decimalPlaces)', 'data[0].toFixed' is undefined)`.

It does not seem like the `Calculate` function is the problem because when I remove it from the code, the issue persists.

```
function Graph({navigation}) {
  const [var1, setVar1] = useState(0);
  const [var2, setVar2] = useState(0);
  const [var3, setVar3] = useState(0);
  const [var4, setVar4] = useState(0);

  let Strompreis;
  if (authentication.currentUser.uid === '7wIwGnxXuNUkSXCfFGEcqsYXZK62') {
    if (global.price === undefined) {
      Strompreis = 0.29;
    } else {
      Strompreis = global.price;
    }
  } else {
    Strompreis = 0.25;
  }

  const Calculate = ({var12, Strompreis12}) => {
    let result;
    if (var12 === undefined || Strompreis12 === undefined) {
      return 0 + '.00';
    } else {
      result = var12 * Strompreis12;
    }
    if (isNaN(result)) {
      return 0 + '.00';
    } else {
      result = result.toFixed(2);
      return result;
    }
  };

  const getStyle = () => ({
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : '-6%',
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./images/BackgroundCropped.png')}
        style={styles.img}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Eigenverbrauch</Text>
        <LineChart
          data={{
            labels: [
              'Jan',
              'Feb',
              'Mar',
              'Apr',
              'May',
              'Jun',
              'Jul',
              'Aug',
              'Sep',
              'Oct',
              'Nov',
              'Dec',
            ],
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [var1, var2, var3, var4],
              },
            ],
          }}
          width={Dimensions.get('window').width} // from react-native
          height={260}
          yAxisSuffix="kwh"
          yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
          chartConfig={{
            backgroundColor: '#009688',
            backgroundGradientFrom: '#009688',
            backgroundGradientTo: '#ffa726',
            decimalPlaces: 1, // optional, defaults to 2dp
            color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
            labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
            style: {
              borderRadius: 16,
            },
            propsForDots: {
              r: '6',
              strokeWidth: '2',
              stroke: '#ffa726',
            },
          }}
          bezier
          style={{
            marginVertical: 8,
            borderRadius: 0,
            top: 90,
          }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.titleEinspeisung}>Zählerstand</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Energieverbrauch in kWh"
          placeholderTextColor="#009688"
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={text => setVar1(text)}
          value={var1}
          returnKeyType="done"
        />
        <Text style={styles.titleEinspeisung}>Aktuellen Kosten!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.titleKosten}>
          Die aktuellen Kosten belaufen sich auf:
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.Kosten}>
          <Text style={styles.textCalc}>
            {Calculate({var12: var1, Strompreis12: Strompreis})}€
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.aktuellerStrompreis}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            Ihr aktueller Strompreis beträgt {Strompreis} €/kwh
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={getStyle()}>
          <NavigationBar navigation={navigation} />
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: `result = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2);` Can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason why you get the ".toFixed is not a function" error might be related to how `.toFixed` can only be used on numbers while input fields typically return strings.

I believe that you might be able to work around this issue by casting the input from a `String` to a `Number` in the `onChangeText` prop function of the `TextInput` component:

```
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Energieverbrauch in kWh"
          placeholderTextColor="#009688"
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={text => setVar1(Number(text))}
          value={var1}
          returnKeyType="done"
        />
```

However, you will have to deal with the case where users enter input that is not a number, which would result in `var1` to be `NaN` and cause further issues. You can circumvent that problem by making sure that the input field is of `type="number"`. Browsers typically don't let users enter non-numbers for this type of input field.